# How Axon framework's sequencing policy works in terms of statefulness

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing, axon

In Axon's [reference guide](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/1.3-infrastructure-components/event-processing) it is written that

> Besides these provided policies, you can define your own. All policies must implement the SequencingPolicy interface. This interface defines a single method, getSequenceIdentifierFor, that returns the sequence identifier for a given event. Events for which an equal sequence identifier is returned must be processed sequentially. Events that produce a different sequence identifier may be processed concurrently.

Even more, in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/axonframework/qATVLytuXDc/sZEZx7BYBQAJ)'s last message it says that

> with the sequencing policy, you indicate which events need to be processed sequentially. It doesn't matter whether the threads are in the same JVM, or in different ones. If the sequencing policy returns the same value for 2 messages, they will be guaranteed to be processed sequentially, even if you have tracking processor threads across multiple JVMs.

So does this mean that event processors are actually stateless? If yes, then how do they manage to synchronise? Is the [token store](https://axoniq.io/apidocs/3.1/org/axonframework/eventhandling/tokenstore/inmemory/InMemoryTokenStore.html) used for this purpose?

Comment: It can be done using optimistic locking at the event store level - like this https://www.michielrook.nl/2016/09/concurrent-commands-event-sourcing/

Comment: That can work in the case if the event bus is an `EmbeddedEventStore`. But what about in case of Kafka? In the documentation it is written that all the events are published to the same topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this depends on what you count as state, but I assume that from the point of view your looking at it, yes, the `EventProcessor` implementations in Axon are indeed stateless.

The `SubscribingEventProcessor` *receives* it's events from a `SubscribableMessageSource` (the `EventBus` implements this interface) when they occur.
The `TrackingEventProcessor` *retrieves* it's event from a `StreamableMessageSource` (the `EventStore` implements this interface) on it's own leisure.

The latter version for that needs to keep track of where it is in regards to events on the event stream. This information is stored in a `TrackingToken`, which is saved by the `TokenStore`.
A given `TrackingEventProcessor` thread *can only* handle events if it has laid a claim on the `TrackingToken` for the processing group it is part of. Hence, this ensure that the same event isn't handled by two distinct threads to accidentally update the same query model.
The `TrackingToken` also allow multithreading this process, which is done by segmented the token. The number of segments (adjustable through the `initialSegmentCount`) drives the number of *pieces* the `TrackingToken` for a given processing group will be partitioned in. From the point of view of the `TokenStore`, this means you'll have several `TrackingToken` instances stored which equal the number of segments you've set it to.

The `SequencingPolicy` its job is to drive which events in a stream belong to which segment. Doing so, you could for example use the `SequentialPerAggregate` `SequencingPolicy` to ensure all the events with a given aggregate identifier are handled by one segment.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Steven. Does this mean that if I set the initial segment count for a tracking processor (`axon.eventhandling.processors[name].initial-segment-count = 4`), then I will have 4 threads processing the events while still respecting the `SequentialPerAggregate` policy? Does it somehow figure out the segment number based on the aggregated id?

Comment: The initial segment count and thread count are separate values you'd need to configure, especially in a config file. If you'd use the `TrackingEventProccesorConfiguration#forParallelProcessing` factory function, you can provide a number which will automatically influence both.

The `SequentialPerAggregate` `SequencingPolicy` does not figure out the number of segments. It only provides the means to deduce a specific value which events should conform to to be put in a `Segment`.

`SequentialPerAggregate` for example uses the `aggregateIdentifier` as that value.